# Add text to bar graph ggplot2 (asterisks for significance)

Tags: r, ggplot2, graph, bar-chart

I have a rather complex graph (at least for me) and I would like to add asterisks for the comparisons that are significant. I have coded the significant comparisons in a separate column of my data frame. Here is my data:

```
data = structure(list(mask = structure(c(1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 
2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 
4L), .Label = c("roi1", "roi2", "roi3", "roi4"), class = "factor"), 
    comp = structure(c(1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 3L, 3L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 
    3L, 3L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 3L, 3L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 3L, 3L), .Label = c("comp1", 
    "comp2", "comp3"), class = "factor"), type = structure(c(1L, 
    2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 
    1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L), .Label = c("rand", "real"
    ), class = "factor"), dv = c(0.5001, 0.5002, 0.5001, 0.5002, 
    0.5002, 0.7658, 0.5, 0.8692, 0.4998, 0.8568, 0.5001, 0.8814, 
    0.5001, 0.5002, 0.5003, 0.5001, 0.5, 0.6943, 0.5003, 0.669, 
    0.5, 0.6205, 0.5001, 0.686), std = c(0.0258, 0.0351, 0.0351, 
    0.0258, 0.0258, 0.0347, 0.0346, 0.0256, 0.0347, 0.0254, 0.0239, 
    0.0351, 0.0351, 0.0347, 0.0256, 0.0347, 0.0256, 0.0258, 0.0348, 
    0.0256, 0.0351, 0.0254, 0.0254, 0.0347), sig = c(0L, 0L, 
    0L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 
    1L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 1L)), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
-24L))

head(data)
  mask  comp type     dv    std sig
1 roi1 comp1 rand 0.5001 0.0258   0
2 roi1 comp1 real 0.5002 0.0351   0
3 roi1 comp2 rand 0.5001 0.0351   0
4 roi1 comp2 real 0.5002 0.0258   0
5 roi1 comp3 rand 0.5002 0.0258   0
6 roi1 comp3 real 0.7658 0.0347   1
```

This is the code for my graph:

```
ggplot(data=data, aes(x=comp, y=dv, fill=type)) +
  geom_bar(stat="identity", position=position_dodge()) +
  theme_bw() + facet_wrap(. ~ mask, ncol=2) + 
  scale_y_continuous(name = "accuracy", limits = c(0, 1)) +
  geom_errorbar(aes(ymin=dv-std, ymax=dv+std), width=.2,
                position=position_dodge(.9))
```

[Current graph](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RCsLE.png)

However, I would like to add an asterisk between the bars where the corresponding real row has a 1 in the sig column e.g. between roi1 comp3 rand and real. The finished graph should look like this:

[Desired graph](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gLwRE.png)

Does anyone have an idea how to do this?

Cheers,
Max

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the following code

```
library(tidyverse)

ggplot(data=data, aes(x=comp, y=dv, fill=type)) +
  geom_bar(stat="identity", position=position_dodge()) +
  theme_bw() + facet_wrap(. ~ mask, ncol=2) + 
  scale_y_continuous(name = "accuracy", limits = c(0, 1)) +
  geom_errorbar(aes(ymin=dv-std, ymax=dv+std), width=.2,
                position=position_dodge(.9))+
  geom_point(data = data[data$sig ==1, ],aes(x=comp, y=0.99), 
             shape = "*", size=8, show.legend = FALSE)
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

You can add a `geom_text` layer to do this. You can set different data for each layer if you need to. In this case, I mutated the input data for that layer to contain the label desired if `sig == 1` and an empty character otherwise.

```
ggplot(data=data, aes(x=comp, y=dv, fill=type)) +
  geom_bar(stat="identity", position=position_dodge()) +
  theme_bw() + facet_wrap(. ~ mask, ncol=2) + 
  scale_y_continuous(name = "accuracy", limits = c(0, 1)) +
  geom_errorbar(aes(ymin=dv-std, ymax=dv+std), width=.2,
                position=position_dodge(.9)) +
  geom_text(data = data %>% mutate(sig1 = if_else(sig == 1, "*", "")),
            aes(x = comp, y = 0.95, label = sig1))
```

[image]